# Can't set innerHTML when using strings that start with '<'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea that will populate another section with what the user inputs and my code works fine as long as I dont type anything starting with "<". Whenever I have a string like "<anything else can follow" that starts with "<", it wont set the innerhtml.

```
var text = "<i wont print"
text = "i will print!"
trans_txt.innerHTML = text;
```

Is "<" some kind of override character for innerhtml? I was wondering if anyone knew what was happening and if there is a way I could change the text var into purely string without having to worry about my string not showing up.

edit: I realized this because the default textarea message is "<text area"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<i` followed by a space is HTML syntax for "Start an `<i>` (idiomatic/italic) [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)" Since the parser doesn't see the end of the tag's definition (that is, a `>`), everything between the `<i` and the end is considered an error and dropped.

If you want to insert *plain text only*, use `textContent` instead:

```js
var text = "<i wont print"
document.body.textContent = text;
```

`textContent` is also faster and safer. Only use `innerHTML` when deliberately inserting HTML markup.

Don't use `innerText` - best to prefer `textContent` instead [in almost all situations](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/).